# C++20: Narrowing between T* to bool

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++20, implicit-conversion

One of the features of C++20 is [Converting from T* to bool should be considered narrowing](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) but perhaps I am not familiar with the history of this and trying to wrap my head around it in terms of what's its use-case/takeaway?

Following is how I have understood narrowing and the use of direct vs copy initialization

```
bool x = 2;   // narrowing
bool x {2};   // can't narrow 2 to bool since {} is more strict than copy initialization
bool x = 1;   // fine: 1 == true
bool x {1};   // can narrow 1 to bool
```

The article says:

1.

> char* argument cannot construct bool alternative.

> Converting from T* to bool should be considered narrowing.

Is it pointing to the example below? What's its usecase? The following compiles fine but is it implying there's narrowing between `char*` to `bool`? Was this not a thing before C++20? Doesn't seem [it](https://godbolt.org/z/f3vqhcYMo)

```
bool p = new char*;
```

2. 

> std::nullptr_t is not convertible to bool, but bool is constructible from std::nullptr_t`

however the following fails (verified [here](https://godbolt.org/z/WYKb16qs8))

```
bool x = nullptr
```

3. Why does storing a double into an int error out but storing T* into a bool doesn't given initializer list prevents narrowing? (using gcc) [sample](https://godbolt.org/z/7qj9h45MP)

```
int value {2.5}; // error - no narrowing conversion
bool res {new int}; // warning - no narrowing conversion
bool res (new int); // WHY does this compile fine?
```

Comment: the linked paper has some description https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1957r2.html

Comment: that's what I am referring to

Comment: yes, just see it.

Comment: ? the questions I have posed are literally based around the points made in this article

Comment: (1) `=` permits narrowing conversions, but `{...}` doesn't. Of course you're not getting any errors with the former. (2) Note that it says "constructible", not "convertible". You need `bool x(nullptr);`.

Comment: @xyf well because you don't link to it directly. I don't see it at first glance.

Comment: @xyf oh I see, I mean "yes, I just realize it after I post the comment". by "yes, (I) just see it". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @appleapple the quotes I copied in the description are taken straight from the article you linked

Comment: Yes, `bool p = new char*;` is **narrowing**.  (It's also **leaking**.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat convertible implying implicit conversion == narrowing, which could be achieved via `=`, hence why `bool x = nullptr` doesn't work? Also, `{}` doesn't allow narrowing so how does `bool x {nullptr}` compile?

Comment: *"convertible implying implicit conversion == narrowing"* I don't understand what you're trying to say. (2) says "constructible but not convertible", meaning only explicit conversions work and not implicit, hence `bool x(nullptr);` works and `= nullptr` doesn't. `bool x{nullptr};` doesn't look narrowing to me (you don't lose information by converting a pointer 0 to a boolean 0) (it's also an explicit conversion).

Comment: `bool x(nullptr)` results in implicit conversion and that's coming from the compiler as a warning

Comment: I think I see the misunderstanding.  **implicit conversion** does not necessarily mean **narrowing**.

Comment: what did you mean by explicit conversion in your previous response? you mentioned `{}` explicit conversion instead of implicit which is with `=`? so how's `bool x = nullptr` implicit but `bool x {nullptr}` isn't?

Comment: Please don't forget `@username`, otherwise we don't get notifications.

Comment: @xyf *"implicit conversion and that's coming from the compiler as a warning"* The compiler warning is spelled incorrectly then. *"how's `bool x = nullptr` implicit but `bool x {nullptr}` isn't?"* Simply because that's how the langauge works. You'll also see the former reject `explicit` constructors, but not the latter.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you can't blame the compiler for that which clearly mentions implicit conversion. Explicit casting is typically done with explicit casting methods (static_cast etc). You can't say there's explicit casting just because of an explicit constructor imo. It's more like direct initialization doesn't require a converting constructor.

Comment: I'm checking the standard, and apparently it doesn't define "explicit conversion" at all. It does define [implicit conversion](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.general#3) though (also see [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.general#:conversion,implicit)).

Answer (score 1):

> Was this not a thing before C++20? Doesn't seem it

Define "before". The proposal [added the change as a defect of the standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1957r2.html). That means it propagates backwards through all applicable C++ revisions. So any new versions of compilers that implement C++17 or earlier should *also* implement this change.

But if you use an [older version of compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/KnW1hMa8z), it won't have this change.

> However the following fails (verified here)
>
> ```
> bool x = nullptr
> ```

Of course it does. "Convertible" and "constructible" aren't the same thing. "Convertible" is short for "implicitly convertible". If `A` is implicitly convertible from a `B`, that means `A x = b;` works.

`A` being "constructible" from `B` means means `A x(b);` works. And `bool x(nullptr);` [in fact works](https://godbolt.org/z/Y9ecExG8z).

Comment: For something to be (implicitly) convertible for copy initialization, you can't have an explicit constructor. Is this the reason `bool x = nullptr` fails? Also, how come you aren't seeing any warning whereas I am? (link in the description)

Comment: @xyf: "*Is this the reason bool x = nullptr fails?*" Neither is a user-defined type, so they don't have *any* constructors. The conversion fails because the standard *says* it fails (or more specifically, says that it doesn't succeed). "*how come you aren't seeing any warning whereas I am?*" I did see warnings. They don't matter; the code still compiles.

Comment: So I can only assume `bool x = nullptr` fails because the implicit conversion fails for god knows what reason? Also, what about the usecase for `bool = new char*`. There's narrowing (implicit conversion) taken place here but what's the key takeaway here? What was like before making this "change" in the standard?

Comment: @xyf: "*There's narrowing (implicit conversion) taken place here but what's the key takeaway here?*" That "narrowing conversions" as a concept pretty much never applies outside of using list initialization.

Comment: @xyf: "*the implicit conversion fails for god knows what reason?*" If the reason why `std::nullptr_t` should not be implicitly convertible to a boolean is not obvious to you, I'm not sure what more I could say on the matter.

Comment: same reason how `int` gets implicitly converted to `B` here, just because of a converting ctor: https://godbolt.org/z/j8eTv4W18

Comment: @xyf so maybe look here: https://godbolt.org/z/4e9db4K96 , I hope this helps

Comment: @xyf: I don't understand what that statement is a response to. `std::nullptr_t` is not a user-defined type, so "converting constructors" don't matter.

Comment: @MaciejPolański yes this just proves my point further. Just because there's no converting constructor implicit conversion is prohibited hence the error. Doesn't answer my original question though, which is the failure in implicit conversion between `nullptr` and `bool` and the construction works fine. Technically they are of different types so makes sense but I was thinking from a deep down logic.

Comment: @xyf: "*yes this just proves my point further. Just because there's no converting constructor implicit conversion is prohibited hence the error.*" None of the types you are talking about are class types. "Converting cosntructors" are therefore **completely irrelevant!** Stop bringing them up as if they were something meaningful in this context.

Comment: @xyf: "*Technically they are of different types so makes sense but I was thinking from a deep down logic.*" What "deep down logic" do you need more than "they are of different types"? The "deep down logic" of implicit conversion is that there is some relationship between the two types, that a value within one of them can mean the same thing as a value in the other (to some extent). Why would you consider this to be reasonable for the relationship between `bool` and `std::nullptr_t`?

Comment: you might want to elaborate on `to some extent` here. Things can get vague pretty easily. Certainly you can store `double` to `int` but the cost of losing precision despite them being of different types, and the resultant value wouldn't be the same double that the user had intended. So basically I'll just assume that the construction works because the standard says so, and the conversion fails because of...well...different types